# Use of stack of tanh layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I am currently reading [this](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf) paper and following is the model used in it. I haven't been able to completely understand what is the purpose of using three tanh layers. I read the usage of tanh activation function, how it can reduce learning time compared to sigmoid activation function but I don't understand why three tanh layers are needed.

[image: Model]

To explain what it is trying to do is take two sentences, add embdedding of each word in the sentence to create two 100d vector, concatenate these two vectors to form a 200d vector and input it to the stack of tanh layer followed by a 3-way softmax since there are classes to classify into.

Comment: That does not seem like a duplicate at all to me. Could you expand more on why you think so?

Comment: @kbrose yes, the question asks why there are 3 tanh layers as opposed to (what i infer is the implied alternative) 0 or 1 layers.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I interpreted the question as the OP thought that the layer _only_ included the tanh function (i.e. no fully connected weight matrix + bias stuff, literally only the activation function). This would be worthy of a question because why would anyone just stack plain tanh's together? Maybe the OP could weigh in?

Answer (score 1):

In your linked paper (you should provide the full citation to avoid link rot) we see the following

> Our neural network classifier, depicted in Figure  3  (and  based 
>   on  a  one-layer  model  in  Bow- man et al. 2015), is simply a stack
>   of three 200d tanh layers

Following the reference through

> Samuel  R.  Bowman,  Christopher  Potts,  and  Christopher D.
>   Manning.  2015.  Recursive neural networks can  learn  logical 
>   semantics. In Proc. of the 3rd Workshop on Continuous Vector Space
>   Models and their Compositionality.

it seems like the authors are using "tanh layer" to mean a fully connected layer with a tanh activation. This is not said outright but it seems heavily implied by the following section:

[image]